# Polygon symbology only shows up outside of polygon after exporting

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, export

In ArcMap the symbology looks fine but as soon as I export the polygon fill color only shows up out side of the polygon.

In ArcMap

[image]

After Exported

[image]

Comment: What format are you exporting the data to?

Comment: Is that a raster?

Comment: If you repair the geometry of the layers involved prior to export does that help?